# Angular SVG with filter not rendering

Tags: angular, url, svg, filter

I'm trying to render an SVG with a filter inside an Angular 6 application, but I cannot get the filter to be applied. Even after trying several solutions already presented to similar questions, as removing the `<base href="/">` or providing the full URL to the filter style.

```
<svg height="200" width="200">
    <defs>
        <filter id="glow">
            <fegaussianblur result="coloredBlur" stddeviation="4"></fegaussianblur>
            <femerge>
                <femergenode in="coloredBlur"></femergenode>
                <femergenode in="coloredBlur"></femergenode>
                <femergenode in="coloredBlur"></femergenode>
                <femergenode in="SourceGraphic"></femergenode>
            </femerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,200 L200,0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
    <path d="M0,0 L200,200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="filter: url(#glow);" />
</svg>
```

Here's an example that I cannot get to render. It contains two lines, of which one should have a glow effect: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awz9dv

If I copy/paste the rendered output to a static HTML page it renders fine...
Not sure what's going on,

Comment: XML is case sensitive - feGaussianBlur, feMergeNode, feMerge etc.

Comment: @MichaelMullany, I did not expect you comment to matter, but the casing actually fixed my issue! Can you maybe move your comment to an actual answer, so I can mark your comment as the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a comment by Michael Mullany about the casing of the filters I got the SVG filters working in Angular, which at first seems strange, because the casing did not seem to matter in a plain HTML file.

But after some more investigation, it seems related to Angular's templating mechanism. Because Angular keeps it's own list of all possible HTML element tags and all SVG tags and attributes, my guess it's related to the fact that the SVG filter tags get assigned the wrong namespace, the HTML namespace, and therefor are no longer picked up by the browser.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.ts

Hope this helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Casing is one issue, but to address name spacing for Angular its best to hint Angular that the XML is subject to SVG name spacing this way:

```
<svg height="200" width="200">
    <svg:defs>
        <filter id="glow">
            <svg:feGaussianblur result="coloredBlur" stddeviation="4"></svg:feGaussianblur>
        </svg:filter>
    </svg:defs>
    <svg:path d="M0,200 L200,0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```